# Do I need to free pointer

Tags: go, garbage-collection

I am implementing queue in Go.

```
type Node struct {
    Value interface{}
    Next  *Node
}

type Queue struct {
    Front *Node
    Rear  *Node
}

func (q *Queue) IsEmpty() bool {
    if q.Front == nil {
        return true
    }
    return false
}


func (q *Queue) Dequeue() (interface{}, error) {
    if q.IsEmpty() {
        return nil, errors.New(constants.EMPTY)
    }

    tmp := q.Front
    result := tmp.Value
    q.Front = q.Front.Next

    if q.Front == nil {
        q.Front = nil
        q.Rear = nil
    }

    tmp = nil // free tmp
    return result, nil
}
```

In the Dequeue function, do I need to free tmp pointer by set it to nil, or Go will do it for me? Please explain for me in detail.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When a variable goes out of scope, it's potentially eligible for GC, the same as if you explicitly set it to `nil`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go has garbage collection, so it will free the memory space that it doesn't hold a reference to.

When the `Dequeue` function ends, you'll lose the reference to the space that was allocated for the variable that you dequeued and the garbage collector will free it. You don't have to nil it out.

Comment: what do you mean by "it doesn't hold a reference to". Can you explain more detail?

Comment: reference == pointer in this case. When you create a new node, eg. like this: `node := &Node{ Value: 3, Next: nil }` Go allocates a memory space necessary to hold one `Node` struct and returns its address to `node` var. If you were to allocate `node` var to something different or lose it by leaving the scope where it existed, the garbage collector would figure out that you don't have any way to access the memory that holds `Node{ Value: 3, Next: nil }` and would automatically free it.

Comment: So in my case, I assign tmp := q.Front, when flow exit Dequeue function. I have no way to access tmp, so Golang will automatically free it, I do not need to assign tmp = nil to free it.

Comment: Yup, that's right. Well, actually it frees q.Front, or rather what was previously q.Front